# C# Lists: initialize with size, why then can't use [] access until after .Add()?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

This works fine with an array:

```
int[] a = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    a[i] = i;
}
```

But this throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException with a list:

```
List<int> a = new List<int>(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    a[i] = i;
}
```

Why is that? I thought that lists used arrays internally.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are initializing the capacity, not the size. The count will still be zero. Initializing the capacity allows an optimization to size the internal data structure (an array) when you know the maximum size when creating the list. This keeps the internal array to a known size and prevents internal array re-sizing as you add the known number of elements.

Answer (score 3):

`new List<int>(10)` creates a new list with the initial *capacity* of 10 items. The list is still empty.

You need to *add* items to it before you can access them by index.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't specify a capacity, your collection will be reallocated several times if it even grows to have 100 elements. This makes populating your list twice as slow.

refer to this [test page](http://dotnetperls.com/capacity)